# How to feed the filament through the material shortage sensor?

Tags: extruder, creality-cr-10, filament-sensor

[image: Sensor]

[image]
I'm just finishing the set-up of a CR-10 Max. It is a new printer.

I don't manage to feed the filament through the material shortage sensor.

I can hear the micro switch click; the LED turns blue, then a few millimeters after that (33 mm total from the entry point), there is something that prevents the filament from going forward. I don't see any switch on the outside of the sensor, and I applied a reasonable amount of force on the filament.

Can you tell me how to troubleshoot this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've designed similar sensor casings, sometimes the filament catches a ridge/ledge or part of the cavity, even when it is chamfered or rounded. The arm of the limit switch pushes the filament up, away from the filament straight path.

Have you tried cutting the filament under a very sharp angle, that may work.

Comment: Thanks. I found the ridge, it was on the side opposite to the microswitch. Cutting at a sharp angle helped. I know it's on this side because that's the only place it still catches something. In the documentation, they don't really tell us why we have to cut he filament,

Answer (score 1):

Here is 3D model that better explains why it was catching and how to remedy the problem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The filament is likely to have some twists and the bevel you create may not be in the correct orientation once it catches the ridge.

The out hole is not chamfered on the inside, as it is drilled from the outside, and I guess a chamfer on the inside is not available at this price range.

I found that twisting the filament 90° at most one way or the other always helps the filament finds its way. It can be tricky because of the small diameter/stiffness of the filament, with the spool still attached to the other end.